# NSPredicate search with NSDate error

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, nspredicate

I'm attempting to get a list of to-do lists that have to-dos >= a certain date.

Data Model: Todolist has many Todos.

The `due_at` field in Todo model is a Date object.

This is the fetch request I'm using and it keeps crashing.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = _dueDateSlider.intValue;
NSDate *datePeriod = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Todolist"];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todos.due_at >= %@", datePeriod];
[request setPredicate:pred];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *todolists = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
-[__NSArrayI compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1018a4c50
An uncaught exception was raised
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, as any other predicate search works fine. `todos.due_at != nil` is fine as well as `todos.content like '%test%'` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the lists that have *any* to-dos >= a certain date, use

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY todos.due_at >= %@", datePeriod];
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know ANY was that important.